# can I display the line numbers using sphinx.ext.viewcode?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using the [sphinx.ext.viewcode](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html) to document my API. Is it possible to display the line numbers on the produced cod-block and if yes how ?

I've tried to find an `html_option` in the docs but I didn't found anything.

Comment: If you are using the [`code-block`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-code-block) or [`literalinclude`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-literalinclude) directive you can use `:linenos:` or `:lineno-start:` to add line numbers next to the source code

Comment: I'm not and that's the point of this extension, files are automatically generated from `.. class::`, `.. function::` etc. directives from my .rst files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I asked this question, the following [PR](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/6319) have been merged to Sphinx and is available starting from v7.2.0.

to add the line numbering in a viewcode output, simply add the following parameter to your conf.py:

```py
viewcode_line_numbers = True
```